# Fetch data from url in background mode ios?

Tags: ios, background, fetch

i need fetch data from server in background mode ios. but when i run app in background, didReceiveData method never called. in foreground it work fine.
when app run in background then app request data from applicationDidEnterBackground method. i cannot why didReceiveData method not call.

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

i use this way may help you..

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

```
     NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic  setObject:string forKey:@"data"];
    [dic setObject:ADDD_DATA_UPGRADE forKey:@"cn"];
    [dic  setObject:@"true" forKey:@"mode"];
    [self login:dic];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
     {

    });
 });
```

}

-(void)login:(NSDictionary*)dic
{

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:UPDATION_ON_SERVER_TIME];
SAAPIClient *manager = [SAAPIClient sharedClient];
[[manager responseSerializer] setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
[manager postPath:@"" parameters:dic success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     if([[responseObject objectForKey:@"status"] boolValue])
     {
         NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
        [self parseResponseFromJson:responseObject];
     }

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:UPDATION_ON_SERVER_TIME];
     NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
 }];
```